# Is calibration of a low blue light OLED display possible?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, display-calibration

Right now I am looking for a new laptop for photo editing, and since I don't want to use a secondary display, I would like to have a laptop with a very good built-in display. I don't want to spend the money for a workstation or content-creation laptop (which would have superb displays I guess) since I mostly edit in Lightroom and don't edit any videos or very large files. But correct color and high contrast are very important to me.

I have bought an Asus Vivobook (the Vivobook S 15 OLED (12th Gen Intel, 2022) K3502ZA-MA059W) because it has a very nice OLED display with a wide color gamut (100% DCI-P3). The problem is: This display has a "low blue light" certification, and my pictures look much too warm compared to my old laptop. I have tried to correct it with the built-in Intel control center for the Iris XE, but couldn't really get a decent correction for it. I am now thinking about buying a display calibration tool, or sending back the laptop, searching for a different one.

But before I do this I would like to know: Can a low blue light display like this even be calibrated so that it looks neutral? (And is a laptop like this even suited for photo editing?)

Comment: I don't know the specifics and would be curious to know myself (judging by phones, OLED displays are perceived differently in many ways), but _if_ it's actually 100% DCI-P3, then it _should_ be possible to calibrate it. In any case, "buying a display calibration tool" would be a good thing to do with any non-sRGB display if you do photoediting. (I guess you'd also need to check that it's compatible with OLED...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought was that it might not be fit to be calibrated, but upon reading some specs of the notebook screen, I found out that it is possible.

See this test here: https://www.anandtech.com/show/17277/the-asus-vivobook-pro-15-oled-review-for-the-creator-in-all-of-us/4

Summary in case the link goes offline:

- *The panel underlying the Vivobook Pro 15 OLED is a Samsung AMOLED part, which other sources have pegged as the ATNA56YX03-0. This means it's a true RGB panel, without any kind of color filters (ala WOLED)...*
- *The Vivobook Pro 15 is marketed with DCI-P3 color support, although that is technically incorrect, as what it offers is actually P3 D65 color support – DCI-P3 is a cinema standard with a different white point.*
- *For brightness levels and contrast, the X-Rite i1Display Pro colorimeter is used, and for color accuracy testing, the X-Rite i1Pro 2 spectrophotometer takes the stage.* (Remark: so you can calibrate it).

And a last:
[image: Color CHart]

- *Finally we have the color checker swatch, which shows the target color on the bottom of the image and the achieved color on the top of the image. This is a relative test, as any inaccuracies in your own display will skew the result, but very much shows how the Vivobook Pro 15 biases towards red.*

Conclusion: It will be calibrate-able, but there is an offset with cyan, which will bias the image towards red a bit. The issue is stronger on higher brightness.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this sums it up pretty good. Maybe the remaining bias towards red is still because of the low blue light certification (I mean it has to have some effect doesnt it?)